# hover element A, show/hide Element B

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a `<div>` element containing an image. Inside that div, I have a `<p>` element which holds some information about the image. I want to hover the `<div>` containing the image and then show or hide the `<p>` element.

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="img/an_039_AN_diskette.jpg" width="310px" height="465px" />
    6 Pharma IT
    <p class="hoverbox">some information</p>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to do so in jQuery?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML markup of what you want to do? I'm a little unclear.

Comment: i m sorry i just forgot to format the code

Answer (score 8):

The following will match all of your images, and target their first sibling having the tag P.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.box img").hover(
      function(){$(this).siblings("p:first").show();},
      function(){$(this).siblings("p:first").hide();}
    );
});
</script>

<div class="box">
  <img src="somefile.jpg" />
  <p>This text will toggle.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I m doing the same.. But My paragraph is around 100 lines. So i have to scroll down on my paragraph to get full content .In this case content will hide when i remove my hover from the A content here(Image).. What should I do

Answer (score 6):

```
      $("css_selector_of_img").hover(
      function () {
        $("css_selector_of_p_element").show();
      },
      function () {
        $("css_selector_of_p_element").hide();
      }
      );
```

See http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover

Comment: where do i put this? When i write that in my head in the document.ready part, it`ll just break the rest of my js.

Comment: Put it, surrounded by <script></script>, at the end of your page, right before </body>, with jQuery that's parallel to using document.ready.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#divwithimage').hover(
       function(){$('#ptag').show();}, //shows when hovering over
       function(){$('#ptag').hide();} //Hides when hovering finished
);
```

Comment: Don't forget your comma to split up the two functions.

Comment: i get this from firebug:
missing ; before statement

Comment: it may have been because of my missing comma between the two functions. I have just tried it and it worked for me

Comment: there is no error anymore, but the effect is still not working. Could it be that the javascript is kinda broken because i created the whole page with includes and a php switch?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="box">
    <img ... />
    <p class="hoverbox">Some text</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('div.box img').hover(
        function() { $('div.box p.hoverbox').show(); },
        function() { $('div.box p.hoverbox').hide(); }
    );
</script>
```