# Need help on displaying text in a div when an Image Link is hovered over.

Tags: css, html

To paint the picture image I have two divs one on top to hold 5 thumbnail pics and the bottom div has 5 lines of text. The idea is when I hover over a picture div I want the project name of it to be displayed on the bottom div. I want this to happen for all 5 pictures. Been searching everywhere and found some things that were close but dead end. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am trying to help a student with their project. I am good with CSS I just can't wrap my head around this task.

Answer (score 3):

### [Simple Demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/Fzyns)

The HTML is pretty simple.  The `.photowrapper` is optional, and the class could be just placed on the the `a`.

```
<div class="photowrapper">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="//placehold.it/200" alt="" />
    <div class="label">Text</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

We need everything to be an inline-block to act like an image.

```
.photowrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.photowrapper a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

We default our label to being transparent.  When our `.photowrapper` is hovered, its text color changes.

```
.photowrapper .label {
  color: transparent;
}

.photowrapper:hover .label {
  color: black;
}
```

If you want the underline, add another rule for `.photowrapper:hover a` where you set the decoration to `underline`.  This disables it on hover and by default.

```
.photowrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

---

### [Absolute Positioning Demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/IgFLz)

With the same HTML, we can position our labels so that they are in the same place.

```
.photowrapper .label {
  opacity: 0;
  color: black; background: yellow;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

---

### Fancyness

You can have supported browsers transition color changing for a less jerky result.  Replace the label style with this:

```
.photowrapper .label {
  min-height: 1em;
  color: transparent;
  -moz-transition: color 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: color 1s ease;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/bDaey)

---

If your label is more than text, you can instead change/animate the opacity.

```
.photowrapper .label {
  opacity: 0;
  color: black; background: yellow;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.photowrapper:hover .label {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/IgFLz)

Comment: +1 for the non js answer, although it's rare you'll find a user with js turned off it's still nice to see not everyone thinks inside the box I do lol.

Comment: I added another example, that more matches yours (with CSS).  I have a policy of, if you can do it with CSS: do it with CSS (well jQuery might be more practical than the absolute position example, because this ignores the flow).

Answer (score 1):

What this does is uses the data attribute to attach a name, then when the image is hovered whatever is in the data attribute is set as the HTML for the p tag with the id "info"

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/HQQsb/

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" data-name="Image 1" class="project"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" data-name="Image 2" class="project"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" data-name="Image 3" class="project"/>
</div>
<div id="infodiv"><p id="info"></p></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".project").mouseover(function(){
        $("#info").html($(this).data('name'));
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $("#info").html('');
    });
});
```

Comment: (+1) Darn, I read the question wrong.  Nice answer.  Doing it with just CSS would be a bit challenging (but doable with absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use javascript or jquery to get it to appear on hover. Someone asked something pretty similar here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119956/hover-element-a-show-hide-element-b
```

Also there are many tutorials that can be accessed from a simple google search on creating a jquery script to do what you're asking. Let me know if you need anymore help or dont understand how to do it.