# Bring up a div to click and hover with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I do a hover or click on the class = "img-1", I want to bring up the class = "block 1" and hide the class = "block-default". Also, I want to  make the default block reappear when there is no action.

```
<style>
.bloc{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
position: absolute;
}

.bloc:nth-child(1){
background-color: #003169;
}

.bloc:nth-child(2){
background-color: #00A8FF;
}

img{
float:right ;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="Bloc">
<div class="bloc">Bloc-1</div>
<div class="bloc">Bloc-2</div>
<div class="bloc">Bloc-defaut</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
<img class="img-1"  title="image-1" src="" />
<img class="img-2" title="image-2" src="" />
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I can not seem to hide the default blog when I click on $(function() {

$('img').hide();

$('img').hover(
function () {
 $('bloc').fadeIn();
}, function () {
 $('bloc').fadeOut();
});
});

Comment: Put that code in the question! It's essential to understand you problem. Looks like you're missing the `.` in the `bloc` selector, as it is a tag, not an html tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hover element A, show/hide Element B](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119956/hover-element-a-show-hide-element-b)

Answer (score 0):

Add you can add an additional class to your default or select it with `nth-child(n)`

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


$('.img-1').on('mouseover mouseout click',function(){


  $('.bloc-default').toggleClass('hide')
})
```

});

css:

```
.bloc{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
}

.hide{

  display:none;
}

.bloc{
background-color: #CC2222;

}

.bloc:nth-child(1){
background-color: #003169;
}

.bloc:nth-child(2){
background-color: #00A8FF;
}

img{
float:right ;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="Bloc">
<div class="bloc">Bloc-1</div>
<div class="bloc">Bloc-2</div>
<div class="bloc bloc-default">Bloc-defaut</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
<img class="img-1"  title="image-1" src="//lorempixel.com/100/111" />
<img class="img-2" title="image-2" src="//lorempixel.com/100/110" />
</div>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jhiOK67iJQWvzi2fKz2w?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var img1 = document.querySelectorAll("[title=image-1]");

img1.onclick = function() {

    var currentClass = (' ' + img1.className + ' ').indexOf(' block-default ') > -1;
    if (currentClass) {
        img1.className =
        img1.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)block-default(?!\S)/g, '');
        img1.className += " block-1";
    } 
    else {
        img1.className =
        img1.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)block-1(?!\S)/g, '');
        img1.className += " block-default";
    }
};

img1.onmouseover = function() {

    var currentClass = (' ' + img1.className + ' ').indexOf(' block-default ') > -1;
    if (currentClass) {
        img1.className =
        img1.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)block-default(?!\S)/g, '');
        img1.className += " block-1";
    }
};

img1.onmouseout = function() {

    var currentClass = (' ' + img1.className + ' ').indexOf(' block-1 ') > -1;
    if (currentClass) {
        img1.className =
        img1.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)block-1(?!\S)/g, '');
        img1.className += " block-default";
    } 
};
```